# Modifying VBA Workbook Consolidation Code to Address Failure When a Column is Blank

Tags: vba, excel

I am having some small problems modifying the following code:

```
Sub combine() 

LastCol = "G"

Folder = GetFolder()

fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename( _
   Title:="Get SAVEAS Filename", _
  filefilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*")
If fileSaveName = False Then
  MsgBox ("Cannot Save file - exiting Macro")
  Exit Sub
End If

Set newbk = Workbooks.Add
Set NewSht = newbk.Sheets(1)
With NewSht
 .Cells.ClearContents
 Folder = Folder & "\"
 FName = Dir(Folder & "*.xls*")
 Do While FName <> ""
  Set bk = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=Folder & FName)
```

---

```
  For Each sht In bk.Sheets       
   ThisbookLastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   If ThisbookLastRow = 1 Then
   NewRow = 1
   'copy header row
   sht.Range("A1:" & LastCol & "1").Copy _
    Destination:=.Range("B1")
   'put filename in cell A1
   sht.Range("A1") = "Workbook"
   End If
   NewRow = ThisbookLastRow + 1


   With sht
   LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   DataRows = LastRow - 1
   Set CopyRange = .Range("A2:" & LastCol & LastRow)
   End With

   'copy data from old workbook to this workbook
   If DataRows > 0 Then
   CopyRange.Copy _
    Destination:=.Range("B" & NewRow)
   'put book name into column A
   .Range("A" & NewRow & ":A" & (NewRow + DataRows - 1)) = _
    FName
   End If
  Next sht
  bk.Close savechanges:=False
  FName = Dir()
 Loop
```

---

```
 'put totals in last row
 LastRow = .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 NewRow = LastRow + 1
 .Range("A" & NewRow) = "Total"
 LastCol = .Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 For Colcount = 4 To LastCol
  Set SumRange = .Range(.Cells(2, Colcount), _
   .Cells(LastRow, Colcount))
  .Cells(NewRow, Colcount).Formula = _
   "=sum(" & SumRange.Address & ")"
 Next Colcount

End With

newbk.SaveAs Filename:=fileSaveName

End Sub

Function GetFolder()
   'Declare a variable as a FileDialog object.
 Dim fd As FileDialog

 'Create a FileDialog object as a Folder Picker dialog box.
 Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
 fd.Title = "Select Excel Workbook(s) Folder"
 'Declare a variable to contain the path
 'of each selected item. Even though the path is a String,
 'the variable must be a Variant because For Each...Next
 'routines only work with Variants and Objects.
 Dim vrtSelectedItem As Variant

 'Use a With...End With block to reference the FolderDialog object.
 With fd

  'Use the Show method to display the File Picker dialog box and return the user's action.
  'The user pressed the action button.
  If .Show = -1 Then

   'Step through each string in the FileDialogSelectedItems collection.
   For Each vrtSelectedItem In .SelectedItems

    'vrtSelectedItem is a String that contains the path of each selected item.
    'You can use any file I/O functions that you want to work with this path.
    'This example simply displays the path in a message box.
    GetFolder = vrtSelectedItem

   Next vrtSelectedItem
  'The user pressed Cancel.
  Else
  End If
 End With

 'Set the object variable to Nothing.
 Set fd = Nothing


End Function
```

Effectively the code is creating a master book out of a selected folder of Excel files.  This is great, however each Excel workbook in my folder has about 30 columns and only 7 are being transferred per file.  I suspect this is because the 8th column, although it has a header, does not have any data in it (it is effectively a blank column).  I suspect the above macro fails to recognize this and subsequently stops when it hits that column and moves onto the next file.  Is there a way to change the code so that this does not happen?  I am not sure what changes in the sectioned off area, or elsewhere in the code, would allow for this.

Comment: Try changing LastCol = "G" to the last column of your sheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest change that is not a major re-write is to change the second line to:

> LastCol = "AD"

That will then copy thirty columns rather than seven.